# NSWindow not displayed when closeWindow command is present

Tags: objective-c, xcode, window, nsprogressindicator

I need progress feedback in my app. Using an `NSWindowcontroller` (subclass `IndicatorWindowController`) that controls a Window containing an `NSProgressIndicator` (`myBar`). Everything works fine if I don't finish the procedure with `[myIWC.myWindow close]`. If I have this command, the window won't even show.

```
- (IBAction)runIndicatorWindow:(id)sender;
{
    IndicatorWindowController* myIWC = [[IndicatorWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ProgressWindow"];

    [myIWC showWindow:sender];

    for (double barLoop=0; barLoop<=100; barLoop++) {
        
        myIWC.myBar.doubleValue = barLoop;
        [myIWC.myBar display];

    }

    [myIWC.myWindow close];//<-When this is not commented out, nothing shows

}
```

Comment: And this surprises you because? `showWindow:` schedules the window to be displayed, likely at the end of the runLoop. But you send it a `close` right away, so of course the window will never show.

Comment: Thanks Gerd, this is just an isolated code from my much larger program. I can put a wailing loop of several seconds after the bar loop and the presence/absence of [myIWC.myWindow close] still has the same effects. Same when it is part of my program where the bar progression get incremented after each of many different parts of lengthy operations. What is the solution? Why is the window "scheduled" to show itself after all that action and how can I make it appear before the action (loop) starts?

Comment: The window is controlled by the runLoop that handles events. That means you actually need to return from your method after opening the window, allow events to flow, then close the window some time later. 

Your code has an additional issue: Your `IndicatorWindowController` instance is not stored anywhere outside that method. That means `myIWC` (and with it the window) will be released  when your method ends, which also means the window never has a chance to be displayed.